# When there are sub populations within a large population how is it treated?

Tags: mean

say I sample 1000 people, 750 of them have a distribution similar to the result produced for all 1000, but 250 produce a distribution which fits entirely into the bottom quartile of the total 1000.

Does this invalidate the overall result for the 1000 people ? Is there any statistical method say hypothesis testing to say that the mean of the sub population is not the same as the mean of the 1000 people ?

Or is it fair game just to lump everyone into the same group ?

Answer (score 2):

Lets make this concrete: Say you measured income on men and women, and women earn on average less than men. You can take all observations together and compute the average income, and it will tell you what the overall average income is. You can use regression analysis and include gender as an explanatory variable, now you measure the average incomes of men and women separately. Both can be meaningful, but they answer different questions.